# Get the react component static property in webpack loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-register

I wrote a webpack loader, in this loader I want to get a static attribute value of the react component introduced in a jsx file in src.

I can use the babel-register in this loader, but the project's webpack configuration seems to be overwritten, and less loader does not take effect.

How to get the static attribute value of component in src in webpack loader?

Thank you!